# Nginx, неправильные редиректы по поддоменам

Tags: nginx

Никак не могу понять почему сервер пускает трафик по любому прописанному в A записях сабдомену на schedule.domain.ru, тоесть я делаю запрос alice.domain.ru -> schedule.domain.ru, так же и с главным доменом, domain.ru -> schedule.domain.ru

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name alice.domain.ru;
    location / {
        return 301 https://google.com/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name schedule.domain.ru;
    location / {
        return 301 https://schedule.domain.ru$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name schedule.domain.ru;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/schedule.domain.ru/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/schedule.domain.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/schedule.domain.ru/chain.pem;

    access_log /var/log/sched_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/sched_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html
Если nginx принял запрос он обязательно его обработает в каком-то серверном блоке. На порту 443 у вас ровно один такой блок так что больше негде обрабатывать

Comment: Нет, вы скорее всего не поняли, проблема в том что при запросе alice.domain.ru он должен делать редирект на google.com, но он проксирует трафик с локалхоста

Comment: @Аесто есть проблема с отображением в браузере? Удаляйте весь кэш, используйте режим инкогнито или чистый браузер. А лучше всего консольные утилиты для проверки новой конфигурации.

Comment: @Аесто покажите вывод `curl -I http://alice.domain.ru` В частности что написано в ответе в заголовке `Location`